# How to incremment value in for each angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, foreach

I have one problem with for each in angular. I wanna increment my value inside forEach in my controller. I take value like string by my API, and when i click on button i need to increment this value. This is my code:

**Controller:**

```
    PostService.getActivity(user)
    .then(function (data) {
        $scope.activities = data.activities;
    });

    $scope.AddToFavorite = function (activity_id, fav_count) {
        PostService.AddToFavorite(activity_id, user)
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log('Like added');
                $scope.acititivty.fav_count = parseInt($scope.acititivty.fav_count) + 1;
            })
    };
```

**HTML - View**

```
<div class="list card activity-card animated fadeIn" ng-switch-default ng-repeat="activity in activities" ng-if="activity.type == 'activity_update'">
    <div class="item item-avatar">
        <img ng-src="{{activity.user.avatar}}">
        <div class="activity-header">
            <h2>{{activity.user.username}}</h2>
            <p am-time-ago="activity.time"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-body">
        <div ng-bind-html='activity.content' class="activity-content"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-body activity-footer row">
        <!-- Favorite-->

        <button ng-click="AddToFavorite(activity.activity_id, activity.fav_count)" class="col-50 add-to-fav"><i class="fa fa-beer violet"></i>
            <span>({{activity.fav_count}})</span>
        </button>

    </div>
</div>
```

I try to do this like:

```
 <button ng-click="AddToFavorite(activity.activity_id, activity.fav_count); activity.fav_count = + parseInt(activity.fav_count) + 1" class="col-50 add-to-fav">
    <i class="fa fa-beer violet"></i>
    <span>({{activity.fav_count}})</span>
 </button>
```

It's work but every time value start equal to 1. If fav_count equal 5 after click they show 1.

Im trying like this in controller:

```
 $scope.activity.fav_count = parseInt($scope.activity.fav_count) + 1;
```

But it part of array inside forEach and i ant change them. How to resolve this problem? I waste a lot of time trying to that.

Comment: Can you provide a working plunker of your code?

Comment: it should be activity.fav_count not acititivty.fav_count right?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen Sorry just mistake. But it still not working

Comment: @Nitheesh Sorry i trying to do that but something wrong with connection  plunker and fiddle doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a repeater, controls are loaded for each activity.
If you would like to count the overall favorites then do the following.

On your controller define a variable:

```
$scope.totalFavorites = 0; //even you can load initial values from DB
```

Don't forget to inject $scope into your controller.

Then on your button click code, do the following.

```
<button ng-click="AddToFavorite(activity.activity_id, activity.fav_count); totalFavorites+=1;activity.fav_count = totalFavorites"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That help) Thank you very much)

Comment: Don't do like this, because if ur changing the data in front end before update on the database, It cause some problems like if any failure occurs while updating in the database the not effecting in the database but the frontend is changed. The users may be misleading

Answer (score 0):

What about just using

```
$scope.acititivty.fav_count++;
```

I am not sure where this value is declared, but at the beginning of your code, you should define it:

```
$scope.activity.fav_count = 0;
```

Alternatively, if this is returned from an API, and the property may or may not exist, you can try:

```
$scope.activity.fav_count = $scope.activity.fav_count || 0;
$scope.activity.fav_count = 0;
```

I am also noting a typo, not sure if this is part of the issue, or a translation to your SO Post:

**HTML**

```
<span>({{activity.fav_count}})</span>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.acititivty.fav_count++; // acititivty != activity
```

Comment: it parse like a string far increment value actually need parse like integer

Comment: I just added some info on initialization the value. I don't see where you are using the second parameter in the function, that should be eliminated if you are just adding a favorite. (Just use _AddToFavorite(activity.activity_id)_)

Comment: Where / why is this a string? Per @graveyardqueen, better help could be provided with a demo, as partial code cannot give full context to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,
Change in controller

```
$scope.AddToFavorite = function (activity) {
    PostService.AddToFavorite(activity.activity_id, user)
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log('Like added');
            activity.fav_count++;
        })
};
```

Change in HTML

```
<button ng-click="AddToFavorite(activity)" class="col-50 add-to-fav"><i class="fa fa-beer violet"></i>
    <span>({{activity.fav_count}})</span>
</button>
```